# Applescript to keep a button pressed until I press it again?

Tags: macos, applescript

I need an extra modifier key which acts kinda like Capslock by using AppleScript - or maybe you've got another proposition?

I would bind it to some key combination in BetterTouchTool.

Comment: Between which kind of states of what do you want to toggle? Something like insert mode and normal mode in vi?

Comment: Yes, exactly something like in vi.

Comment: Does it have to be with AppleScript? Sticky Keys is essentially for this exact purpose (but for disabled people, not specifically for making other modifiers behave like caps)

Comment: What _EXACTLY_ do you have in mind? S.th. like a continuously pressed letter ("a" or "b" or whatever), or is it a "shift-lock" / "option-lock"? . . . I would like to know this as I gave the first answer below but may have been mistaken about your actual aim ...

Comment: What I need is something working like capslock - when I press down on that 'special key' it turns it's state to 1. Then every other key press is registered by system as 'special key + another key' until I press that 'special key' again which turns it's state to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite simple "self-regulating" way to switch between modifier keys ***WITHOUT being able to read their state*** could be to utilize their innate "effect" on a user's keyboard.
Write two scripts:

```
  [script 1:]  tell application "System Events" to shift key down

  [script 2:]  tell application "System Events" to shift key up
```

**Toggling shift**: apply a shortcut (e.g.) **"option o"** to the 1st script, **"option *shift* o"** to the 2nd one.

Now, each time you press **"option o"** when calling the scripts, *this will **STILL toggle** "shift"* as "System Events" will receive **"option shift o"** in case of a **previously active shift key** ...

(Another way might be to use a global variable  or even a plist file.)